# How to get parent of parent node in firebase realtime database in android?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

My firebase realtime database structure is given below.

[image: Firebase realtime database]

I am having that phonenumber field value. I need to get that parent of parent node.

Tryed this query to return immediate parent. But unable to get that itself. Here roomId is `"9444XXXXXX"`.

```
mFireBaseDatabaseNest = mFireBaseInstance.getReference(Constants.DATABASE_NEST);
    mFireBaseDatabaseNest.orderByChild("phonenumber").equalTo(roomId).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            if (dataSnapshot.exists()) {
                String key = dataSnapshot.getChildren().iterator().next().getKey();
                Log.v(TAG, "found: " + key);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
```

Need help to change this query.

Comment: What is the result of `dataSnapshot.getChildCount()` ?

Comment: @MD Child count is 0

Comment: Instead of describing how you database looks like, please add your database structure as a JSON file or at least as a screenshot. Please also responde with @AlexMamo

Comment: @AlexMamo Updated my question with screenshot.